# Is it possible to clone the git repositories when installing NPM packages from git?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I have a `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "some-module": "git+ssh://git@github.com/IonicaBizau/some-module.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I do `npm install` everything is installed correctly, but I would like to install the package from my repository by cloning the repository too, so in `node_modules/some-module` I will have a git repository cloned from GitHub.

How can I do that? Is there a built-in option for that or should I build my own tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created [**`gpm`**](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-gpm) - a tool that install the dependencies from git.

`git + npm === gpm`

---

To install gpm do:

```
npm i -g gpm
```

Then you can do:

```
gpm -i some-module
```

This will install the dependencies from git repositories, recursively.